# App Engine force login from facebook

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I have a google app engine that handled logging in to Yahoo and Google though the OpenID mechanism and it works well. I have added the facebook connector (Javascript Library) and it to works well with the exception that I can't get the app to think it's authenticated. I know why this is occurring because Facebook provides its own "connect" and it's not OpenID.

Is there a way I can call the GAE framework once authenticated to allow for `login: required` pages to work?

I want to add others like twitter and microsoft, but it's a real pain if I can't get the GAE to honour the fact it's authenticated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Isaac below I did stumble upon this URL at facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

The redirect URL you specifiy gets a few tokens that facebook thinks you need... in their case  `access_token={access-token}&expires={seconds-til-expiration}`.

From the time when I managed to break my app because of the ajax loading I noticed that google OAuth put you back on `/_ah/login?continue=<new final end point>` which processed the tokens seemlessly and then did something within the framework to register the user as authenticated, then puts you back on the URL you specified in the first place. It's this I want to understand.

**Further edit**

I've found a few bits for example:

http://code.scotchmedia.com/engineauth/docs/index.html

It's python but it looks like it is possible to handle multiple authentication types from multiple vendors (the link shows things like twitter and facebook) so this does look possible.

I tried creating a new User on the framework, but there is no setCurrentUser() on the UserService object.

The only thing I can think of now is forging the authentication cookie. Anyone know the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe facebook has an oauth login flow.  These links might help:

- http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

If you can't get oauth to work, you could use a `@login_required` decorator on your endpoints

```
import functools

def login_required(func):
  @functools.wraps(func)
  def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user = users.get_current_user()
    if current_user or check_facebook_login(self):
      return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    elif self.request.method == 'GET':
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))
    else:
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.write('Forbidden')
      self.error(403)
  return decorated

class QueryHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @login_required
  def get(self):
     ...
```

Comment: That for the links, but this is what I am using, like I said it works great, the thing is that if I lock a page in the app.yaml with `login:  required` the framework always attempts to authenticate the user because the facebook connector didn't do the callback. I read the bits in the documentation about using a full page model, but I can't find any further reference to it, or any reference to a the callback I need... and if I know that I can just implement that :)